# In Ios i need to accepted the length of three sides of a triangle as an input and the output should indicate the type of triangle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have figured out the logic but dont know how to write code.
Im not sure how i use the if else statement on ios

If a==b && b==c 
Eqilateral
If a==b or b==c or c==a
Issoceles 
Else 
Scalene

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This looks like a homework assignment..... you can easily learn how to write if statements for a wide range of languages through many mediums.  This is not a tutorial site, this is a problem solving question and answer site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set for determining the triangle type

```swift
func triangleType(lengthSet: Set<Int>) -> String {
        switch lengthSet.count {
        case 1:
            return "Equilateral"
        case 2:
            return "Isosceles"
        default:
            return "Scalene"
        }
    }
```

Usage : 
`self.triangleType(lengthSet: [2,2,3])`

It's recommended to evaluate your input count before calling the function ;)

Comment: In this scenario, I would recommend taking in 3 parameters and building the set inside the function to prevent a mistake like a line or a rectangle being treated as a triangle.  Other than that, upvote for creativity.

Comment: Yes, it could be done in this way too, the main goal is to show using set for compare values. I agree with your solution that taking parameters and build set inside the function

Answer (score 0):

For the if statement itself, you can simply right it like so (assuming you want to return it as a string from a function or something):

```swift
if a == b && b == c {
    return "equilateral"
}

if a == b || b == c || c == a {
    return "issoceles"
}

return "scalene"
```

You don't need `else` statements after the `return`s, as each `return` breaks out of the function if it's hit.

If you prefer, you could also use `else` statements to further clarify what's happening:

```swift
if a == b && b == c {
    return "equilateral"
} else if a == b || b == c || c == a {
    return "issoceles"
} else {
    return "scalene"
}
```

Comment: You would want to use an else if for better readability.

Comment: I disagree. It's unnecessary and implies the else is actually doing something. But at this point, it's a matter of preference ‍♂️.

Comment: Black box the code after your if statements.  If you see an if/else if, you know the code you are about to look at is one or the other. If you have an if/if, you are then forced to evaluate further the behavior your code is going to perform.  Lot of things are “unnecessary” but should be done to add readability.

Comment: I suppose that's true. Maybe in a more non-trivial case, that would be more apparent.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include both examples.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately our coding habits happen during the trivial coding phases, better to start off with good habits, then use bad habits when being rushed or lazy then starting with the bad habits and trying to adopt good ones.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I prefer ternary operator `return a == b && b == c ? "equilateral" :
       a == b || b == c || c == a ? "issoceles" :
       "scalene"`

Comment: @LeoDabus  lol that is even more ugly.

Comment: This is your opinion. All you need to  make it “beautiful” is to break it up into 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: @LeoDabus  double ternary is really hard to read, without parentheses they can become a nightmare.  When you start reviewing thousands of lines of code, the last thing you want is to parse a ternary statement lol.

Comment: Hard is relative. Like I said for me it is easier. Btw I hate parenthesis in Swift conditions where it is not needed. The problem is your background coding habits

Comment: @LeoDabus ok whatever, not going to argue about relativity of difficulty when we were discussing code readability (which is to make code readable to everybody, not just the developer)